# How to get variable from url in php

Tags: php

I have this url and i want to take variable values in php from this url how to do this.

```
http://example.com/core/click/3492/3389
```

Comment: What variable value do you want to get? `3492` or `3389`? Or is it something else?

Comment: Please show any code samples you may have come up with in an attempt to solve your problem. Is "core" important?, is "click" important?

Comment: i want to get 3492 value in php

Answer (score 2):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to return the path part of the url.

```
<?php
// returns: /core/click/3492/3389
$path = parse_url('http://example.com/core/click/3492/3389', PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Then you can [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the path into its parts:

```
$path = explode('/', ltrim($path, '/'));

print_r($path);

Array
(
    [0] => core
    [1] => click
    [2] => 3492
    [3] => 3389
)
```

Comment: The second parameter to `parse_url` is a great way to get just the path too without the additional variable assignment.

Comment: what to do if this 3492 value is a variable value

Comment: @Mark you won't have issues if the value changes only that if you're trying to access it like say `$path[2]` and then the url changes to `/core/foo/click/3492/3389`, but you didn't mention that in the question.

Comment: sir only 3492 and 3389 are variables and remaining path is not changed.

Comment: Ok, you should not have an issue accessing them like `$path[2]` and `$path[3]`.

Comment: Extract just the numbers `$ids = array_values(array_filter($path,'is_numeric'))`